# Viewing Tables in the AxTOControl using ArcObjects

Tags: arcobjects, .net

I was wondering if anyone out there has written a Table filter for the AxTOCControl in the ArcObjects Library.

I've rolled my own Table view for now in C#, but would like to try and keep things consistent.

If you could point me to any resources I would be very appreciative.